Nginx no encuentra archivo "fullchain.pem"
estoy realmente preocupado por que tengo un proyecto terminado y no se lo puedo entregar al cliente por este problema. Llevo 3 dias.
Instale en mi instancia ec2 donde tengo el backend server.js corriendo nginx yc cerbot.
Cuando corro sudo certbot --nginx -d fotolonchodb.com -d www.fotolonchodb.com 
Me devuelve
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.

2024/11/13 17:38:44 [emerg] 2504#2504: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/fullchain.pem, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\n2024/11/13 17:38:44 [emerg] 2504#2504: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/fullchain.pem, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file)\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n')

Tengo esta configuracion en "sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/fotolonchodb.com"
# Configuración para el tráfico HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name fotolonchodb.com www.fotolonchodb.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/chain.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # Asegúrate de que Certbot pueda hacer su validación para obtener el certificado SSL
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}
  

estos son los otros dos comandos que fallan obviamente y no puedo genererar los certificados ssl:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-45:~$ sudo nginx -t
2024/11/13 17:49:14 [emerg] 2532#2532: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fotolonchodb.com:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-45:~$ sudo systemctl reload nginx
nginx.service is not active, cannot reload.

ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-45:~$ sudo certbot certonly --nginx -d fotolonchodb.com -d www.fotolonchodb.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.

2024/11/13 17:52:18 [emerg] 2546#2546: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fotolonchodb.com:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\n2024/11/13 17:52:18 [emerg] 2546#2546: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fotolonchodb.com:2\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n')
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-45:~$ client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer

el front esta subido ya en vercel con todos los dns vien y todo redirige bien pero caundo quiero usar un servicio tira este error :
POST https://www.fotolonchodb.com/api/auth/login 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Por favor si alguien me puede dar una mano, estoy desesperado. Gracias

Para que certbot funcione necesita que nginx escuche en el puerto 80 (http sin encriptación). Como es la primera vez que lo ejecutas, aun no se creó el certificado en /etc/letsencrypt/live/fotolonchodb.com/fullchain.pem y por eso te da error al iniciar. Si sacas la parte de la configuración que hace que escuche en el puerto 443, y lo pones sin https debería andar.

Para lo de las peticiones POST tenes que configurar un reverse proxy para la ruta /api que apunte a donde este escuchando tu backend.

Mady te agradezco tu respuesta. Pero por favor ayudame, no sabes lo mal que estoy hace 3 dias.  Estoy intentando lo que me dijiste pero algo hago mal. No hay alguna manera de escribirte por otro lado ? aca no me deja pegarte el codigo entero en  la respuesta.
Por favor.

Escribeme que te sale aca y veo si puedo ayudarte: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol
